# How can I change the code to avoid runtime error (AddressSanitizer)?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I'm solving a leetcode question and I'm faced with this error.

> AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
> =================================================================
> ==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address (pc 0x000000316d72 bp 0x7ffc6ca44b90 sp 0x7ffc6ca44348 T0)
> ==31==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
> ==31==Hint: this fault was caused by a dereference of a high value address (see register values below).  Dissassemble the provided pc to learn which register was used.
> #4 0x7f2548e8e0b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
> AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
> ==31==ABORTING

I search the Internet and I find that the error is about dereferencing a null pointer.
Below is my code, and the error occurs at line 18 and line 19.

```cpp
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        ListNode* ans;
        ListNode *tmp1 = l1, *tmp2 = l2;
        while(tmp1 && tmp2){
            if(tmp1->val == tmp2->val){
                *ans = ListNode(tmp1->val);
                *(ans->next) = ListNode(tmp2->val);
                ans = ans->next->next;
                tmp1 = tmp1->next;
                tmp2 = tmp2->next;
            }
            else if(tmp1->val < tmp2->val){
                *ans = ListNode(tmp1->val);
                ans = ans->next;
                tmp1 = tmp1->next;
            }
            else{
                *ans = ListNode(tmp2->val);
                ans = ans->next;
                tmp2 = tmp2->next;
            }
        }
        if(tmp1 != NULL || tmp2 != NULL){
            ListNode* tmp3 = (tmp1 != NULL) ? tmp1 : tmp2;
            while(tmp3){
                *ans = ListNode(tmp3->val);
                ans = ans->next;
                tmp3 = tmp3->next;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Though I have already known where the problem is, I don't know how to mend this problem.
I think it is reasonable.
(this is my first post and English is not my first language, if I do anything wrong please tell me, thanks!)

Comment: If this is supposed to create a new list, you need to dynamically allocates nodes (but then, you should be able to just use the existing list interface as-is, without explicitly creating any nodes). If this is supposed to destructively merge the lists, you should not create any nodes at all, but just change the pointer structure. It's impossible to say how you should fix this without knowing what it should do.

Comment: If you use `-fsanitize=address`, also add `-g` or `-ggdb`. It will then most often show you the exact line number where bad things happened.

Answer (score 1):

`ListNode* ans;` is a pointer to a `ListNode` it is **not** a `ListNode`. It can point to a `ListNode`, but it does not.

Then here:

```
*ans = ListNode(tmp1->val);
```

You try to assign to a `ListNode` when there is no `ListNode`. Dereferencing `ans` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

A quick examination shows **ans** is not initialized to point to anything.
A few lines later you assign to the thing pointed to by ans.
***ans** = ListNode(tmp1->val);

I suspect you really need to assign to the pointer, instead of the thing pointed to.   **ans = ListNode(tmp1->val);**

```
  ListNode* ans;
    ListNode *tmp1 = l1, *tmp2 = l2;
    while(tmp1 && tmp2){
        if(tmp1->val == tmp2->val){
            *ans = ListNode(tmp1->val);
```